# how to get parameter from commandline when running rcp in command window?

Tags: java, eclipse, command, rcp

as we know， we can run eclipse in command line as follows:

> > eclipse.exe -clean

I need run my eclipse rcp program in the same way

> > myrcp.exe path

then how can I get the parameter "path" in myrcp code?

thanks~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform

Platform.getCommandLineArgs();
```

Check this [article](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2008/06/21/passing-parameters-to-eclipse-rcp-via-the-command-line/)